# Make footer stick to the bottom without being sticky

Tags: css

I have a footer that is used through out my web app, I need it to be shown at the bottom of the screen if the content is less than the screen size, but not stick if the content is bigger (i.e. I need to be seen only if you scroll down to find it if the content is bigger than the screen size)

I found multiple questions and topics discussing both separately, but not together.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```css
head, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>awesome page</h1>
<p>awesome content</p>
<div class="footer">
  awesome footer
</div>
```

Comment: Same issue as @Daniel's answer below

Comment: my solution works if content is bigger as screen -> footer is on bottom of page and you need to scroll down to it (i made some changes)

Comment: I tried it on my app, on the contrary, it always sticks down to the bottom of the browser, not the app. I don't need to scroll down to find it

Comment: did you add position relative to your body and html?

Comment: I've added it to html, not body, when I added it to body, it "floated" in the bottom, it didn't even stick to the bottom

Comment: i don't know what you mean, if you add position relative to the html it stays on bottom of page unless the content gets bigger as the page

Comment: Ah, I found that there was an added padding to the html, which caused the white space below the header, now it is as intended, the body and html are both relatively positioned, the footer is absolute, still the footer is sticking to the bottom of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Set the body or a containing element to have a min-height of the 100vh and then position your footer absolutely at the bottom of the of the element:

```css
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: firebrick;
  position: relative;
}

footer {
  background: lime;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried something like that before, the thing with it is that it keeps sticking to the bottom of the page, i.e. if there's content to exceed the size of the page, I don't need to scroll down to find the footer, it will be always shown, that's now what I need

Comment: Your initial question says that you don't want to have to footer stick if the page content is increases and here you do?

Comment: Nope, I said that "I need to be seen only if you scroll down to find it if the content is bigger than the screen size"

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: Maybe try and give a visual example of what you mean and add it to the original post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169326/discussion-between-user1712638-and-daniel).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with flexbox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
      }
      .all {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      .content {
        background-color: red;
      }
      .footer {
        background-color: green;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="all">
      <div class="content">
        Content...
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        Footer...
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need to support some older versions of ie, so it won't work with them unfortunately